# Remove ',' fromove last line of the file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, inplace-editing

I have flat file with data as

```
cast ( (emp_ID)  as varchar(2000) ),
cast ( (emp_name)  as varchar(2000) ),
```

I want to remove the `,` from the last line in this file. The output should be:

```
 cast ( (emp_ID)  as varchar(2000) ),
 cast ( (emp_name)  as varchar(2000) )
```

I am using the following command:

```
tail -1 select_stmnt.txt | sed 's/,/''/g' >> select_stmnt.txt
```

What I get is:

```
  cast ( (emp_ID)  as varchar(2000) ), 
  cast ( (emp_name)  as varchar(2000) ),
  cast ( (emp_name)  as varchar(2000) )
```

Removal of the `,` is working fine, but instead of the modified line replacing the original, it is appended, which I don't want.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
sed '$ s/,$//g' yourInputFile
```

The first dollar($) will be used to select the last line.

Comment: @mklement0:- Yes, that can be removed :) Thanks for pointing!

Comment: It displays me the correct o/p in the screen, but the file is not changed. It displays :  cast ( (emp_ID)  as varchar(2000) ),
 cast ( (emp_name)  as varchar(2000) )                                                    I did this : sed '$ s/,$//g' select_stmnt.txt

Comment: I got my mistake - I used the sed -I , it updated the file. What does ',$' mean here  and why is 'g' not required ? I know 'g' means global and it is doesn't make sense here. How does it understand to remove only the last ',' ? Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @SamirSingh:- As I said in my answer. The first $ isactually identifying the last line.

Comment: @SamirSingh:- Also if the answer helped you then you can accept the answer. A right tick mark turns green when clicked.

Comment: @SamirSingh: `,$` means: match a `,` only if it it is the _last character_ on the _line_: `$` _inside a regex_ matches the end of the input line (pattern space), and is a standard regex feature; `$` as a Sed _address_ (the 1st `$`, _before_ the regex) is a Sed-specific construct that applies the regex logic of `$` by analogy to input _lines_ and therefore only matches the last _line_.

Comment: @SamirSingh: As for why `g` is not required: The `s///` function's `g` flag, as you state, means _global_ substitution, i.e., it means that _all_ matches of the regex on the line are replaced.
Given that the regex at hand only matches at the _end_ of the line (due to use of anchor `$`), there can only ever be 1 match at the most, so `g` has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-i` to edit files in-place:

```
sed -i '$s/,$//' select_stmnt.txt
```

Comment: Helpful; note that just `-i` (with the option-argument omitted to indicate that _no_ backup file should be created) works with _GNU_ Sed; on BSD-like systems, including OSX, you must use `-i ''`.